# MAAS node memory detection problem

Tags: server, juju, maas, ram, openstack

We're trying to setup MAAS for a school project. And we're having a problem where our nodes are detected with 0 GB memory. The nodes in question are older SuperMicro bladeservers; SBA-7121M-T1. With 2x 6-core Opterons and 24GB (6x4GB) ram.

I've looked at some other questions posted here and I saw that MAAS use the lshw command to list the hardware properties. And this is where our problem is. The xml report have id's for memory:0 - memory:7, and our nodes have 8 dimm slots. But these contain DIMM3 - DIMM7 in the first 5 id's, the next two are empty and the last id has info about a memory controller.

So my question is two-fold:

1 - Is it possible to manually edit nodes commissioned in MAAS? So that I can add the correct amount of RAM.

2 - Should I bug report the lshw issue? Or is this more likely a bios issue with our nodes?

We're trying to get Juju to bootstrap MAAS so we can deploy Openstack but this 0 memory problem have halted our progress. :/

We're running Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS and MAAS/Juju version 2.1.2.

Thanks.

Comment: OP abandoned MaaS and Juju according to their own answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we got no response here. Or anywhere else for that matter. We've discarded MaaS and Juju and gone for manually installing Openstack on our servers. A bug report have been sent for the lshw command so hopefully in the future this problem is fixed. But we don't have the timeframe to wait any longer.